# Jquery with AJAX - Posting URL String

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i'm using the below code to post a url, with variables in the string to a specific ip address (xxx.xx.xx.xxx). The software developer says there is no issues with my code or the IP permissions, but it just wont work and i'm told that permissions are denied by the AJAX. Am i writing the AJAX call incorrectly? Thanks for any tips ...

```
            <script>
                jQuery(document).on("click", "#idofbutton", function(e) {

                    var variable1 = jQuery("input[name='variable1']").val();
                    var variable2 = jQuery("input[name='variable2']").val();
                    var variable3 = jQuery("input[name='variable3']").val();
                    var variable4 = jQuery("input[name='variable4']").val();
                    var variable5 = jQuery("input[name='variable5']").val();
                    var variable6 = jQuery("select[name='variable6'] option:selected").val();
                    var variable7 = jQuery("select[name='variable7'] option:selected").val();

                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx/Admin/.functions/non_agent_api.php?source=http://www.example.com&user=USERNAME&pass=PASSWORD&function=add_lead&lead_id=XXXX&variable4=' + variable4 + '&first_variable3=' + variable3 + '&variable5=' + variable5 + '&variable2=' + variable2 + '&variable1=' + variable1,
                        success: function(data) {
                            alert('success - http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx/Admin/.functions/non_agent_api.php?source=http://www.example.com&user=USERNAME&pass=PASSWORD&function=add_lead&lead_id=XXXX&variable4=' + variable4 + '&first_variable3=' + variable3 + '&variable5=' + variable5 + '&variable2=' + variable2 + '&variable1=' + variable1);
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            alert('fail - http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx/Admin/.functions/non_agent_api.php?source=http://www.example.com&user=USERNAME&pass=PASSWORD&function=add_lead&lead_id=XXXX&variable4=' + variable4 + '&first_variable3=' + variable3 + '&variable5=' + variable5 + '&variable2=' + variable2 + '&variable1=' + variable1);
                        },
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Comment: Learn about [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Comment: Does that mean my method is incorrect or are you recommending a better way of doing it? If so, what is the benefit? Thanks.

Comment: You only can use ajax on same host unless you use jsonp with callback()

Comment: So CORS is the best option to post a url link with variables, in the background whilst posting a PHP form?

Comment: If you have control over the server at xxx.xx.xx.xxx, you need to send the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header with the response. Also, learn about preflighted requests.